# identifying which rows are present in another dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, which I'm told share some rows. That is, for some indices, (i,j)_n df1.loc[i] == df2.loc[j] exactly. I would like to find this correspondence.

This has been a tricky problem to track down. I don't want to "manually" inquire about each of the columns for each of the rows, so I've been searching for something cleaner.

This is the best I have but it's not fast. I'm hoping some guru can point me in the right direction.

```
matching_idx=[]
for ix in df1.index:
    match =df1.loc[ix:ix].to_dict(orient='list')
    matching_idx.append( df2.isin(match).all(axis=1)  )
```

It would be nice to get rid of the for loop but I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rows in each dataframes are unique, you can concatenate the two dataframes and search for duplicates.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'B': ['a', 'c']})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['c', 'a'], 'B': ['c', 'a']})

>>> df1
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  c

>>> df2
   A  B
0  c  c
1  a  a

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# Returns the index values of duplicates in `df2`.
>>> df[df.duplicated()]
   A  B
1  a  a

# Returns the index value of duplicates in `df1`.
>>> df[df.duplicated(keep='last')]
   A  B
0  a  a
```

Comment: I believe PYOak has you beat in simplicity

Comment: But you lose the index location of the row containing the duplicate. Note the first example is indexed at `1`, the location of the dup in `df1`.  The second example is indexed at `0`, the location of the dup in `df2`

Comment: Agh you're right. I'm giving you the correct answer for giving the best answer for the question even though I'm implementing PYOak's solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do a merge that joins on all columns:

```
match = df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1.columns))
```

Comment: I was trying for an embarrassingly long time trying to get "merge" to work... messing around with "indicator" , "inner", and "on_left" etc. etc.

Thank you very much for the solution!!